# Несуществующий элемент в unordered_map

Tags: c++, containers, unordered-map

1. Что возвращает `test["hello"]`?
2. Что будет, если мы вызовем `fun(test["hello"])`, но внутри функции `fun` не будем присваивать значение, а потом вызовем `test.find("hello")`. У нас найдется элемент? Если найдется, что там будет (нуль, мусор...)?

Код:

```
void fun(int& val) {
    val = 900;
}

int main()
{      
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> test;
    fun(test["hello"]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `test["hello"]` вернет ссылку на значение для ключа `hello`; если такового нет - создаст его со значением по умолчанию (нулем).
2. Найдется, со значением 0.

Не понимаю, почему бы 1. не почитать об `unordered_map` в книге или в Интернете, и 2. почему бы не скомпилировать простейший тестовый код и [посмотреть, что будет](https://ideone.com/0oKwSg)?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void fun(int& val)
{

    cout << val << endl;
    val = 900;
}

int main()
{      
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> test;
    fun(test["hello"]);

    cout << test["hello"] << endl;

}
```